# Replace the data in the existing workbook on specific worksheet using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, replace

It might sound simple but I couldn't get it done.

I have created this dataframe

```
df_weekly = pd.read_excel(directory + 'Weekly Report.xlsx', sheet_name='Weekly SAP extract')
df_master = pd.read_excel(directory + 'Product Master.xlsx', sheet_name='OutputA')
df_cancellation = pd.read_excel(directory + 'Rejection.xlsx')

df_weekly.rename(columns={'Material': 'PC9'}, inplace=True)
df_weekly.rename(columns={'Rej.Reason (SL)': 'Cancellation Code'}, inplace=True)

df = pd.merge(df_weekly, df_master[['PC9', 'Gender', 'Category']], on='PC9', how='left')
df2 = pd.merge(df, df_cancellation[['Cancellation Code', 'Rej.Reason description']], on='Cancellation Code',
                   how='left')
```

**Goal is to**: data on Weekly report excel file (specifically on Weekly_SAP_extarct sheet) should be **replaced** **with** the info captured with **df2** data frame.

Added this code:

```
df2.to_excel('vl1.xlsx')

df_vl1 = pd.read_excel(dri2 + 'vl1.xlsx')
df_vl1.to_excel(Path, sheet_name= 'Weekly SAP extract', index= False)
```

But now the problem is that all the other tabs in Weekly SAP extract is deleted. How can I do the same thing without deleting other tabs?

Comment: What is the problem here? When you run what happens? Which part exactly does not work for you?

Comment: here everything works perfectly but I need to add the code which will help me to achieve the goal.

Comment: I have added the new line of code with new problem

Comment: Can you share how looks the data and which part of the data you want replace?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant share the data. I want to replace the old data in Weekly Report.xlsx with df2 dataframe.